# Not getting response from CCAvenue?

Tags: php, codeigniter, payment-gateway, ccavenue

I have integrated the [CCAvenue payment gateway](http://integrate-payment-gateway.blogspot.in/2012/01/ccavenue-payment-integration-php.html) everything is working fine except I am not able to get response data from CCAvenue.

After successful transaction I am just seeing a thankyou page of CCAvenue but it is not autorefreshing to my redirect url.

I integrated in Codeigniter.

Also I want to tell you that currently my ccavenue merchant id is registered with lets say **abc.com** but because of some reason I am working on **def.com/ghi** .

Please help me to get out of it because there is no live chat option on CCAvenue.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [ccavenue payment gateway not getting money while deducting from account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786651/ccavenue-payment-gateway-not-getting-money-while-deducting-from-account)

Answer (score 2):

You need to activate the working key from CCAvenue Panel in settings & options -> working key -> click on submit.

By default radio button is on Activate and you have to set on deactivate. **See image below.**
It should look like this.

[image]